# Flask app throwing pickle.load 500 error on login on Windows but not on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pickle, werkzeug

I am new at coding and here and I tried googling, I can't resolve my issue, so please show a little patience and not excessive laconism.

This error message is throwed at any redirect, and it is always the same, I can't track it for my life.

I've created a Flask app using PyCharm named application.py. My problem happens on login on 127.0.0.1:5000 (redirection to index), and it throws a fairly cryptic error stack, but not a single message is directed at application.py, so I don't even know which code snippet to upload. Database is not the source of the issue, because I see that it is getting updated. This same program works on Ubuntu VM without a hiccup. I think this may be some kind of a system proxy issue, I have a site blocker called Freedom (freedom.to), but closing this app doesn't seem to fix the problem now (it used to though, I thought it was it, but now it is driving me mad, because I actually made some progress). I tried few combinations in Windows proxy settings, maybe one even worked in the past, now the don't (I have the default).

Attached is the attempt of formatting traceback of an logging in attempt, [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Suz.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "c:\users\mateusz\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_pp
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\mateusz\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "c:\users\mateusz\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\app.py", line 1632, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "c:\users\mateusz\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\app.py", line 1858, in process_response
    self.save_session(ctx.session, response)
  File "c:\users\mateusz\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask\app.py", line 924, in save_session
    return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
  File "c:\users\mateusz\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\flask_session\sessions.py", line 355, in save_session
    total_seconds(app.permanent_session_lifetime))
  File "c:\users\mateusz\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\werkzeug\contrib\cache.py", line 769, in set
    self._prune()
  File "c:\users\mateusz\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-
32\lib\sitepackages\werkzeug\contrib\cache.py", line 725, in _prune
    expires = pickle.load(f)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.
```

Comment: Plz, post the stacktrace in your question.

Comment: Line 4 of the text is a link to imgur, it didn't want to format as code